# Unique key auto generated in Spring Boot Entity

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entity

I have a primary key in my entity table which is autogenerated but now I want unique keys to be auto generated so how to do it
Please help me out.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "director")
    public class Director {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id")
        private long id;
    
//how to make this field auto generated like above one
        @Column(name = "subid", unique=true)
        private long sub_id;
```

My database table picture is here please refer
[image: table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use timestamp or `static AtomicLong` counter as `sub_id` value. Try to define method with annotation `@PrePersist` in your entity class and your JPA provider will execute it before persisting an object.

*Note: using timestamp in concurrent environment may lead to collisions and values won't be unique.*

```
private final static AtomicLong subIdCounter = new AtomicLong(System.nanoTime());

@PrePersist
void sub_id() {
    this.sub_id = subIdCounter.incrementAndGet();
}
```

Comment: It's saying cannot set sub_id to null value

Comment: Are you saving new object to DB or update existed? `@PrePersist` method is invoked only before INSERT operation. For UPDATE operation there is another annotation. Is this method invoking while inserting new object? Check in debug

Comment: Why the sub_id value is negative

Comment: What data type you use for `sub_id` in DB? Long is 64-bit signed integer, so in MySQL you have to use BigInt type

Comment: I typecasted it to integer

Comment: when I did long in entity and bigint in mysql then it worked fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a short study it seems that that Hibernate supports the feature of generated values only with fields annotated with `@Id`. With `@Id` and default `@generatedValue` Hibernate creates - depending on the database and dialect used - appropriate way to generate the value of **id** field. usually this is something like creating a *sequence* and setting the column definition like (***examples are from Postgres 12***):

> id bigint not null nextval('director_id_seq'::regclass)

Interesting thing is that this is done by issuing create statement like this:

> create table director (id  bigserial not null, primary key (id))

So, the column type ***bigserial*** actually generates sequence that is used to insert default value to the id column.

There are two options it you want to generate the value for column **sub_id** as it is generated to the column **id**. Both are database dependent.

Just create the sequence manually to the database and alter column sub_id to fetch the default value from the sequence.

OR

Change your column definition to use appropriate column type, like:

```
@Column(name = "subid", insertable = false,
        nullable = false, unique = true, columnDefinition = "bigserial")
private long sub_id;
```

This will cause Hibernate to generate table like:

> create table director (id  bigserial not null, subid bigserial not null, primary key (id))

and result to a column like:

> subid bigint not null nextval('director_subid_seq'::regclass)

But again: this is database specific stuff.

**Also note**: that JPA is aware only of the value that is stored to the **id** field. The subid is inserted to the database table but the sub_id field is not populated until entity is refreshed in its persistence context.

Comment: I am using MySQL not aware with Postgre but in SQL I can't find any solution but the solution just before your answer is giving unique results but just they are all negative I need to resolve that or if you can provide me any thing on SQL then also it's better